# Symmetric non-degerate bilinear form B

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.

Give an example of a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $B$, which is not an inner product.

I know we need to show $B(u,v) = B(v,u)$ but i have no idea how to calculate $B(u,v)$ where $B$ is a bilinear form and $v$, $u$ are vectors in $V$. The notion $(v,u)$ makes no sense to me.(I also do not understand the notion of $\langle v,u \rangle$ in an inner product space, i cant see what is being calculated here)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the bilinear form induced by $B$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
B(u,v) = v^TBu.
$$
It can't be an inner product, since $B$ is not positive-definite.